# Partial template specialization only for a single function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I've a template where I want to use a pointer type or an instance type as the template parameter. An Example:

```
class FOO {};

class ItemGetter {
    virtual FOO * GetItem(int index) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class ArrayContainer : public ItemGetter {
    T *array;
    ArrayContainer(T * array) {
        this->array = array;
    }

    /*
     * A lot of other functions.
     * I want to write them only once
     * ....
     */

    /* If the T Parameter is an instance Type */
    FOO * GetItem(int index) {
        return &this->array[index];
    }
    /* If the T Parameter is an pointer Type */
    FOO * GetItem(int index) {
        return this->array[index];
    }
};

void usage() {
  FOO fooArray[100];
  FOO * fooPointerArray[100];

  auto bar1 = ArrayContainer<FOO>(fooArray);
  auto bar2 = ArrayContainer<FOO*>(fooPointerArray);
}
```

How can I specialize the `GetItem()` function for the pointer and the instance variant (without writing all the other functions twice)?

Comment: you want `GetItem` to return a `U` when `T==U` and when `T==U*` ? I wouldnt do that, because it breaks expectations. If I have a container of `T` then I want to insert and retrieve `T`s not `T*` or `T` with pointer removed. Just keep it simple

Comment: btw if all occurences of `T` appear as `T*` then imho you better remove the `*` and let the user decide whether they want to store pointers or objects

Comment: What do you mean by pointer type? Just (cv-qualified) `FOO *`, or are smart pointers included?

Comment: @tobi303 That would be fine, but It's not possible in my case. My case is a little bit more complicated as my example ...

Comment: @Useless Only standard pointers, no smart pointers

Comment: Can `T` be something different than `FOO`/`FOO*` ? as partial specialization of method is not allowed, but full specialization is allowed.

Comment: So just write an overloaded helper function `FOO* GetItemHelper(FOO **array, int index)` and `FOO* GetItemHelper(FOO *array, int index)`. A single instance of your method will forward to the correct overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defer to an overloaded free function:

```
#include <cstddef>

class FOO {};

template<class T>
T* get_t(T* array, std::size_t index)
{
    return array + index;
}

template<class T>
T* get_t(T** array, std::size_t index)
{
    return array[index];
}

template<class T>
class ArrayContainer {
    T *array;
public:
    ArrayContainer(T * array) 
    : array(array)
    {
    }

    /*
     * A lot of other functions.
     * I want to write them only once
     * ....
     */

     auto GetItem(std::size_t index)
     {
         return get_t(array, index);
     }

};

void usage() {
  FOO fooArray[100];
  FOO * fooPointerArray[100];

  auto bar1 = ArrayContainer<FOO>(fooArray);
  auto bar2 = ArrayContainer<FOO*>(fooPointerArray);

  FOO* f = bar1.GetItem(2);
  f = bar2.GetItem(5);
}
```

or, for better encapsulation, derive privately from a services class which exports the getter function overloads as static members.

```
#include <cstddef>

class FOO {};


struct ArrayContainerServices
{
    template<class T>
    static 
    T* ImplementGetItem(T* array, std::size_t index)
    {
        return array + index;
    }

    template<class T>
    static
    T* ImplementGetItem(T** array, std::size_t index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }
};

template<class T>
class ArrayContainer 
: private ArrayContainerServices  // note - private inheritance
{
    T *array;
public:
    ArrayContainer(T * array) 
    : array(array)
    {
    }

    /*
     * A lot of other functions.
     * I want to write them only once
     * ....
     */

     auto GetItem(std::size_t index)
     {
         return ImplementGetItem(array, index);
     }

};

void usage() {
  FOO fooArray[100];
  FOO * fooPointerArray[100];

  auto bar1 = ArrayContainer<FOO>(fooArray);
  auto bar2 = ArrayContainer<FOO*>(fooPointerArray);

  FOO* f = bar1.GetItem(2);
  f = bar2.GetItem(5);
}
```